# Start Activity every time app is launched

Tags: android, android-activity, sharedpreferences

My app opens `MainActivity` but I actually want to open `LoginActivity` when the app is launched. I've tried some solutions like:

```
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(PACKAGE_NAME, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    int currentVersion = info.versionCode;
    this.versionName = info.versionName;
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int lastVersion = prefs.getInt("version_code", 0);
    if (currentVersion > lastVersion) {
        prefs.edit().putInt("version_code", currentVersion).apply();
        startActivity(new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
    }
```

And

```
    boolean firstboot = getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF",MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("firstboot", true);

    if(firstboot) {
        //place your code that will run single time
        startActivity(new Intent(ScheduleActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
        getSharedPreferences("BOOT_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().
                putBoolean("firstboot", false)
                .commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your Activity in your Manifest file such as:

```
<activity android:name=".LoginActivity">
   <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```